# System.Identitymodel.Tokens.jwt without issuer possible?

Tags: c#, jwt

This question is quite specific to the JwtHandler library found here: [JWT Handler NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)

I'm trying to create a JWT, using RSA keys for the signature as well as validate this JWT. However I can't seem to shed the "Issuer" variable ("iss") from the jwt. If I don't include it, the validation failes, even when I specify the "ValidateIssuer = false" in the TokenValidationParameters.

Can I use this library, without needing to specify the "iss" variable at all times, or is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: any updates on this ? did u stumble on any answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the source code, I found there is no way to not have the issuer field, even though the standard (RFC7519) has it as optional. I resolved the issue by creating a subclass of JwtSecurityTokenHandler, and override the method ValidateToken() to fix up the issuer there. Next, I handed it over to base.ValidateToken().

I've also gotten the question from my peers why I want to change or remove the issuer from the jwt token, and how this doesn't impair the security aspect. To answer that question: I'm only planning on using public/private key certificates to sign the jwt tokens, who already have an issuer tied to them. Checking the issuer again would be doing some work twice.

**UPDATED ANSWER**
The System.Identitymodel.Tokens.Jwt has been updated to v5, and I strongly recommend to update to this version. It fixes the Issuer issue. A downside of this update is that it has some more dependencies (Microsoft.Identitymodel.Tokens, Microsoft.Identitymodel.Logging, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq) and having to retweak your code to a slighty different interface.